# How to find the number of days between two dates for dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, date, pandas

How do I go about finding the number of days between the all the particular start date ranges in df1 and the according end date in df2. Then dividing the particular row in df1 by the number of days within the specific row (including the division of the particular kWh value and writing if to df1).

For example:

df1:

```
      64           65      START DATE
0     54.37        65.37   2013-05-03 00:00:00
1     43.52        51.23   2013-06-05 00:00:00
```

df2:

```
    Start Date  End Date     kWh 
 0  5/3/2013    6/5/2013     59,120 
 1  6/5/2013    7/2/2013     60,400
```

Updated df1:

```
      64           65           kWh       START DATE
0     1.647575758  1.980909091  1791.51   2013-05-03 00:00:00   # all columns except date is divided by 33
1     1.611851852  1.897407407  2237.037  2013-06-05 00:00:00   # all columns except date is divided by 27
```

33 is the number of days between df1 Start Date 5/3/2013 & df2 End Date 6/5/2013

27 is the number of days between df1 Start Date6/5/2013 & df2 End Date  7/2/2013

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What's the relation btw `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: @ako, the start date ranges are the same between df1 and df2

Comment: So to be clear--Start Date is a potential join field? You talk about the Start Date as a range?

Comment: @ako, I would like to determine the number of days between the start date of df1 and the end date from df2 referencing the same start date which they have in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, convert all dates to timestamps:

```
# Sample Data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({64: [54.37, 43.52], 65: [65.37, 51.23], 'START DATE': ['2013-05-03 00:00:00', '2013-06-05 00:00:00']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start Date': ['5/3/2013', '6/5/2013'], 'End Date': ['6/5/2013', '7/2/2013'], 'kWh': [59120, 60400]})

# Convert dates to timestamps.
df1['START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['START DATE'])
df2['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start Date'])
df2['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End Date'])
```

Now, join the `End Date` from `df2` to `df1`.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['Start Date', 'End Date', 'kWh']], 
                how='left', left_on='START DATE', right_on='Start Date')
```

Calculate days between start and end dates:

```
days = (df1['End Date'] - df1['START DATE']) / pd.offsets.Day(1)
```

Let's clean-up the merged data:

```
df1.drop(['Start Date', 'End Date'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Finally, some gymnastics to divide `df` by the calculated number of days:

```
df1.update((df1[[64, 65, 'kWh']].T / days.values).T)
>>> df1
         64        65 START DATE          kWh
0  1.647576  1.980909 2013-05-03  1791.515152
1  1.611852  1.897407 2013-06-05  2237.037037
```

Comment: What would be the most efficient means of implementing `df1.update((df1[[64, 65, 'kWh']].T / days.values).T)` if I have a large amount of columns per say 64,65,66.....80?

Answer (score 2):

Join the two dataframes, convert to datetime and subtract:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Date':['5/3/2013', '6/5/2013'], 'End Date':['6/5/2013', '7/2/2013'], 'kWh':[59120, 60400]})
pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])
```

Result:

```
0   -33 days
1   -27 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you want the days:

```
df['delta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])
df.delta.dt.days
```